# Using CacheCow to Cache Based On Parameter

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, cachecow

I have a webapi endpoint that looks like the following in my Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetPerson(
      string term = null,
      string workspace = null)
    {
        try
        {
            logger.Info("AvPerson start: " + DateTime.Now);
            if (term == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            ICoreAVData api = MvcApplication.Container.Resolve<ICoreAVData>();

            List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
            persons.AddRange(api.GetAllPersonsForTerm(term, workspace));

            if (persons == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(persons);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }
    }
```

The `term` parameter can vary constantly but the `workspace` parameter displays what is relevant to the user.  The user will not leave his own workspace, so that parameter will be constant from a user perspective.

I wonder if it is possible to have CacheCow cache based on the workspace parameter.  ie. If workpace1 then cache it, if workspace2 then cache that separately.

I recognize that I will have to have add some kind of logic to invalidate that workspace specific cache.  I'm not asking about that, because I believe I know how I might do that.  I want to know if I can have a separate cache entry per workspace parameter.

Here is my routing setup for this controller:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "avperson",
          routeTemplate: "api/v1/avperson/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "avperson", id = RouteParameter.Optional }

       );
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is to change the routing.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "avperson",
      routeTemplate: "api/v1/{workspace}/avperson/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "avperson", workspace = "all", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Doing this will create a separate cached entry for each workspace which can then be validated or invalidated according to need.